# Ito integral with weakly singular integrand

Tags: st.statistics

How is the Ito integral $\int _0^a \frac{1}{(a-s)^\alpha} dW_s$ with $0<\alpha<1$ defined?

Comment: Conditional on $\alpha < 1/2$ and $a>0$, isn't $\int_0^a \frac{1}{(a-s)^{\alpha}} dW_s \sim \mathcal{N}(0, a^{1-2 \alpha}/(1-2 \alpha) )$ ?  This follows from Itô isometry and independence of the increments of the Brownian motion $W_s$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Nawab, how about a numerical approximation for $\int_0^a \frac{f(s)}{(a-s)^\alpha}dW_s$?